# Explode HTML around H2 tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following HTML code.

```
<p>demo1</p>
<h2>demo2</h2>
<p>demo3</p>
<h2>demo4</h2>
<p>demo5</p>
<span>demo-5</span>
<h2>demo6</h2>
<p>demo7</p>
<p>demo8</p>
```

I want to break that into an array of strings like this. Is there any way to do this using js or PHPdom?. Any help will be appreciated.

```
["<p>demo1</p>","<p>demo3</p>","<p>demo5</p><span>demo-5</span>","<p>demo7</p><p>demo8</p>"]
```

**It is not necessary that there will be only a p tag. Any HTML tag can be there. I just want to extract content separately between adjacent H2 tag including on top and bottom.**

Comment: I assume there's some logical reason you can't just use `$('p')`?

Comment: The goal conflicts with the title. According to the title, I'd expect a result like `["<p>demo3</p>","<p>demo5</p>"]`. Which one is correct?

Comment: The lack of leading h2 makes this a little hard

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no it will not. It will not group.

Comment: You're right. I missed the combined p/span in the third and fourth elements of the output

Comment: Wait a minute.  Is this a php task or a javascript task?  It seems that there are too many tags on this question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. Without the leading heading tag, I would approach this a bit differently.

I would select all of the elements and loop over them pushing them to an array. When I detect a heading, I would add a new array and loop until I find the next heading and repeat.

You can either just build the string or append to an array and join.

```js
var elems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")];

var result = elems.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  if (elem.matches("h2")) {
    acc.push([]);
  } else {
    acc[acc.length-1].push(elem.outerHTML);
  }
  return acc;
}, [[]]).map(arr => arr.join(''));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>demo1</p>
  <h2>demo2</h2>
  <p>demo3</p>
  <h2>demo4</h2>
  <p>demo5</p>
  <h2>demo6</h2>
  <p>demo7</p>
  <p>demo8</p>
</div>
```

Just a string, no array

```js
var elems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")];

var result = elems.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  if (elem.matches("h2")) {
    acc.push('');
  } else {
    acc[acc.length-1] += elem.outerHTML;
  }
  return acc;
}, ['']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>demo1</p>
  <h2>demo2</h2>
  <p>demo3</p>
  <h2>demo4</h2>
  <p>demo5</p>
  <h2>demo6</h2>
  <p>demo7</p>
  <p>demo8</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you just are considering the "p" tag.  But there might be other HTML tags as well.

Comment: @GauravYadav You edited it... lol That was not there when I added the question. So it is easy.... change the code to look for h2 and not p.

Comment: Thanks !! It works fine for static  HTML. What do you suggest for dynamic HTML?Is there any alternative for " [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")]" for handling dynamic HTML?

Comment: I mean HTML content is generated by some form element like  <textarea class="wrapper"></textarea>.

Comment: So you trigger the code when the page updates.

Comment: I mean I  can just capture element like $("#wrapper").html().There is no update. Form data will be submitted and stored in a database. I want to process it before submitting it to the database.So i asked if there is an alternative of [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")];
 for dynamic HTML

Comment: Still have no clue why running `[...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")];` is not going to work? It runs when you want it to run and gets the current html....

Comment: ```<textarea class="wrapper"  rows="25" cols="200" type="text" ></textarea>```. How would you capture HTML from this element ?

Comment: textarea does not have HTML.... That is text. If you want to get HTML, you would have to convert it to HTML and read the elements. You really should of had that up front because that is a totally different question.

Comment: I just gave an example. In real, HTML comes from a text editor. So no need to convert text to html.It is already available.

Comment: So what is your issue.... you have to read it when the content changes....

Comment: Issue is ```[...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")]``` does not catch HTML if HTML is not present in the page.But In this case we are using text editor then we have to catch HTML using Jquery or js  like ```$("#editor").html()```.So any alternative you have to grab HTML using js or  jquery rather than class  and convert it in the array same way you did already with static HTML using ```[...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *")]``` ?

Comment: If `$("#editor").html()` gets the data, then a perfectly good DOM selector can get the data. I CAN NOT HELP since I have no clue what your page is, what the editor is, etc.... again, this is a different question that what you originally asked.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem like you need adjacency at all!

This code will get the outerHTML of all top-level paragraphs within body.

```js
Object.values(document.querySelectorAll('body > p')).map(o => o.outerHTML)
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want for h2, just change the variable test

```
var result = [];
var test = $('p');
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    result.push(test[i].outerHTML)
}
```

output:

```
["<p>demo1</p>", "<p>demo3</p>", "<p>demo5</p>", "<p>demo7</p>", "<p>demo8</p>"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p')).map(el => el.outerHTML);
```

it's faster than:

```
Object.values(document.querySelectorAll('body > p')).map(o => o.outerHTML)
```

but this is the fastest:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).map(el => el.outerHTML)
```